# Sleuth traceId cannot propagate in Quartz job

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm working on a Spring Boot project with `spring-boot-starter-quartz` and recently I have added `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` to add traceId for each request. However, when a job is automatically triggered by the system, it cannot propagate traceId like when calling action in controllers or services. Do I have to customise sleuth logging or something else to propagate the traceId to other services ?

Sample:
When I normally call in controller, sleuth works fine and I have traceId propagated to other services

```
2020-06-03 14:37:02.148 [my-scheduler,1966e2d37a2d7713,1966e2d37a2d7713] JobSchedulerController.startScheduleJob:97 17812 --- [nio-8201-exec-3] c.p.s.controller.JobSchedulerController  : Started scheduler job with id 2
```

However, when my job is automatically trigggered, no traceId is propagated, hence other services will not have that traceId as well.

```
2020-06-03 14:37:02.219 [my-scheduler,,] JobListener.jobToBeExecuted:30 17812 --- [ryBean_Worker-2] c.p.s.listener.JobListener        : DEFAULT.SampleJob is going to start...
```

Comment: Which version of Sleuth are you using?

Comment: I'm using sleuth 2.1.2.RELEASE and quartz 2.1.7. Both are extended from ```<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>```

Comment: Please upgrade to the latest version and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by upgrading to `spring-boot-starter-parent` 2.3.0.RELEASE with `spring-cloud-dependencies` Hoxton.SR5